# Where can I find org.apache.common libraries

Tags: java, apache, import, package

I need library for org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.DescriptiveStatistics
and that means I need org.apache.common libraries. Where can I find or download the libraries?

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Turing85 Does that apply here? The OP is not giving us requirements and asking, "_here's my requirements now what libraries exist to do this?_". Rather, the OP _knows_ what library s/he needs and is asking where they can go to download them. Or does the "find" part of the rule cover this case? (p.s. I'm genuinely curious if this rule applies here).

Comment: @Slaw Well... it is as written: No questions finding a software library. OP is looking for a (specific) software library, thus s/he asks us to find it. The vote to close was in my opinion the "lesser evil". The alternative would have been a downvote for no research. This is just my interpretation of the rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download binaries from the Apache Commons Math project:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi

Another way is to convert the project to Maven and add Maven dependency in pom.xml.

Maven link:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3/3.0

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven will find it for you in the repositories and download automatically.

You can search for open-source libraries at https://mvnrepository.com. If you find the artifact there, you will have a link to the author website and license terms.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this site: [findjar.com](http://www.findjar.com/index.x).